# How can I use morewrites and memoize?

Tags: pdftex, write, capacity, morewrites, memoize

Consider the following MNWE, which I'm compiling with pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikz}
  \draw (0,0) -| (1,1);
\end{tikz}
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile with the error

```
! I can't write on file `{.//prawf.700EB6A4550C47FDDA18E01DBED7CCDC.memo}'.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.229   \draw (0,0) -| (1,1);
                             
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name:
```

I'm guessing this might have to do with the use of `\write16` in `memoize.sty` and `advice.sty` since `morewrites.pdf` says

> **TEXhackers note:** The revised `\newwrite` allocate stream numbers
> starting at 19. This might break some code that expects stream numbers
> to be less than 16.

However, the `\write16` in both cases is invoked in code which, as I understand it, is for tracing purposes and off by default. So I'm not certain if this is the problem or not.

Nonetheless, I tried adding, for example,

```
\makeatletter
\def\advice@trace#1{\immediate\write\@unused{[tracing advice] #1}}
\def\mmz@trace#1{\immediate\write\@unused{[tracing memoize] #1}}
\makeatother
```

but this was obviously a stupid idea because it made no difference at all. That is, the following code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\advice@trace#1{\immediate\write\@unused{[tracing advice] #1}}
\def\mmz@trace#1{\immediate\write\@unused{[tracing memoize] #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikz}
  \draw (0,0) -| (1,1);
\end{tikz}
\end{document}
```

But as soon as I uncomment the call to `morewrites`, compilation breaks with the error reported above.

So I'm not clear whether this is simply the use of `\write16`, whether I've missed less obvious uses of `\write16` or if there's a further incompatibility here.

I'm aware that using luaTeX might avoid the need for `morewrites`, but the documents where I need `morewrites` are sufficiently committed to pdfTeX that I'll probably just avoid `memoize` if using it requires switching engines.

What causes the error and is there a way I can work around it in pdfTeX?

Before somebody asks if I really need `morewrites`, David Carlisle told me I needed `morewrites` after some change to LaTeX several years ago.

[That is, is there any chance I might be able to have my cake and eat it, too? A sort of self-perpetuating cake of some kind ....]

Comment: The document does indeed compile with `lualatex` (even with `morewrites` loaded).

Comment: @AlanMunn That's expected. `morewrites` bails out if luatex is used. It issues a warning, but that's all.

Comment: do you really need morewrites? if in your real document you remove it do you get an allocation error on allocating a new `\write` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think so. I can see the number of new writes in the log file. To reduce them, I'd have to change the way I've setup glossaries, I think. For example, I could use `bib2gls` rather than `xindy`. But that would mean converting all the databases. I know there's a conversion tool, but I'm not sure how messy it would get.

Comment: @cfr you can write any number of files from classic tex, what you can't do is have more than 16 files open for writing at the same time. I don't know what xindy is doing here but is really need that many open streams?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure. `glossaries` allocates 16 new writes (streams 20-35). In general, `glossaries` requires one more write than the number of glossaries in the document. There is a `savewrites` option in version 3 but the documentation says it is best avoided, will slow compilation and get some page numbers wrong. It suggests `scrwfile` instead, but I'm not sure whether that's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 1/2024: With the newest version of morewrites it should work.

======

The problem is that the `morewrites` package is rather old. It doesn't know that the various file primitives now allow braced arguments. That means that if you compiled this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite{./blub.txt}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write\mywrite{blub}
\immediate\closeout\mywrite
bluba
\end{document}
```

then it works fine in texlive 2023 and writes the file `blub.txt` but errors in texlive 2017 as it tries to write the file `{./blub.txt}` with the braces (which kind of works) and the inner slash (which the OS doesn't allow) and can't resolve this:

```
! I can't write on file `{./blub.txt}'.
```

`memoize` makes use of the new syntax, and the redefinitions of `morewrites` which reinstates the "old" syntax then lead to similar errors:

```
\immediate\openout\mmz@out{\mmz@cmemo@path}% doesn't work in older tex systems.
```

See also the bug report: https://github.com/blefloch/latex-morewrites/issues/19

Answer (score 3):

Ulrike has explained the issue, but if you *really* need `morewrites` (and usually, it's not needed) and you don't fancy tracing through both packages to bring them in to line, you can do the following (as long as your OS allows)/

**Note this is a step towards a workaround, avoiding the error, but does not produce usable output**

```
mkdir "{."
```

then when `morewrites` tries to write

```
{./example.700EB6A4550C47FDDA18E01DBED7CCDC.memo}
```

including the braces, rather than giving an error it will write the file

```
example.700EB6A4550C47FDDA18E01DBED7CCDC.memo}
```

in the directory (folder) `{.`

So you end up with a weirdly named file ending in `}` in a weirdly named directory starting with `{` but it does actually work.

---

Note this allows  `\input{./foo}` to avoid an error and has a new interpretation as `foo}` in directory `{.`. Unfortunately `memoize` also uses newer primitives that have always accepted brace forms
such as `\pdf@mdfivesum{./foo}` so these refer to the intended (but now non-existant) file `foo` in the current directory. So the above avoids the error but `memoize` fails in various ways. A real fix would be to update `morewrites` (or the pdftex engine) both of which are not impossible to imagine happening, but not actually done.

Comment: Weird, Windows actually allows such directories.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Er ... who/how?

Comment: Cleaned up a bit ....